# I need a location to buy the eureka seven ao bracelet silver edition

Tags: merchandise, eureka-seven, united-states

The bracelet is made by jam home made. There is a gold, silver and other editions. I need silver or whichever is closest to the real color. I need a website that isn't Japanese or at least ships to America. Thank you.

Also please be sure to specify if they are sold out.

Comment: [the jam home made link](http://www.jamhomemadeonlineshop.com/fs/official/JEA-BR003) for those that need it

Comment: Id like a link that wasn't in Japanese, and the item isn't sold out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After looking around a bit on the jam site itself and plenty of other sites that offer the bracelet. Which by the way can be browsed in English using the O so lovely google translate engine [for example](https://translate.google.nl/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jamhomemadeonlineshop.com%2Ffs%2Fofficial%2FJEA-BR003). I found out that most of them are out-of-stock, and marked the product as the following.

> Release date 2012 SS [spring and summer release items]
>
> The item is sold out already, and it is no longer in production. It won't become available again for orders.

leading me to believe that this is a [special/limited edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_edition) collectors item by now, which is not obtainable through online stores any more.

Most likely you have to find somebody that already owns one, and wishes to sell it if you really want a original. If you just want it because of how it looks or for a cosplay, you could most likely get a jeweller nearby you to recreate the actual bracelet, after which you probably only have to rope it yourself. Unless off course the jeweller also can do this for you.